# How do I convert this code to use FlowRouter?

Tags: javascript, meteor, collections, routes, flow-router

I have only used Iron-router vaguely, and as it stands I want to convert from a project I found very useful that used iron-router. What's the best approach to adapt this code to use Flowrouter?

```
CourseController = AppController.extend({
    waitOn: function() {
        // course ID
        var courseID = this.params._id;

        // Course subscriptions
        return [
             // Wait for the course to be available
            this.subscribe("singleCourse", courseID),
        ];
    },
    data: function () {
        // Return the course
        return Courses.findOne();
    },
    onAfterAction: function () {
        // Get the course ID from the URL parameters
        var courseID = this.params._id;

        // TODO: uncomment the following and figure out why it is generating a browser console error

        // Get the course from the database
        //var course  = Courses.find(courseID).fetch()[0]; // select the zeroeth array item

        // Set the site title for SEO
        //Meta.setTitle(course.title);
    }
});
```

Comment: Flow router does not have a waitOn subscription methodology. They suggest to subscribe collections in the template. This link will help https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router#subscription-management. They also have a triggers enter and exit function which may help

Comment: You could use flow-router-extra, which has waitOn and lots of other goodies: https://github.com/VeliovGroup/flow-router